# Order by count in Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

RuleCategory has many Rules.  I want to list the RuleCategories by how many rules they have.

I am using Rails 5.2.1, but when I do a group by and try to order by count(*), I get an error message because I am using raw SQL.

```
RuleCategory.joins(:rules).where(rules: {edit_status: [Rule::EDIT_STATUS_SYNCHED, Rule::EDIT_STATUS_EDIT]})
.group(:category).order('count(*)').limit(5).pluck(:category, :id).to_a

DEPRECATION WARNING: Dangerous query method (method whose arguments are used as raw SQL)
called with non-attribute argument(s): "count(*)". Non-attribute arguments will be disallowed
in Rails 6.0. This method should not be called with user-provided values,
such as request parameters or model attributes.
Known-safe values can be passed by wrapping them in Arel.sql(). (called from irb_binding at (irb):2)
```

How do I put a count statement in the order clause?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Deprecation warnings in the rails are written really well. They usually tell you what you have to do to fix them. Look at the last line of the warning:

> Known-safe values can be passed by wrapping them in Arel.sql(). (called from irb_binding at (irb):2)

It is telling you to use `Arel.sql()` function if you are sure, that your code is correct and it is safe to use the raw SQL directly in the `order` SQL clause. It should be used in the following way:

```rb
RuleCategory
  .joins(:rules)
  .where(rules: {edit_status: [Rule::EDIT_STATUS_SYNCHED, Rule::EDIT_STATUS_EDIT]})
  .group(:category)
  .order(Arel.sql('count(*)'))
  .limit(5)
  .pluck(:category, :id).to_a
```

*(New lines added just for the readabilty)*

See the part with the `order` clause:

```rb
  .order(Arel.sql('count(*)'))
```

This should fix the deprecation warning.

Comment: Mostly I agree with "Deprecation warnings in the rails are written really well."  However, in this case, I wonder about "Known-safe values", as safe from what?  Also, I have not found good documentation on Arel, so Arel is a mystery to me.

Comment: It actually says that too: `This method should not be called with user-provided values, such as request parameters or model attributes.` - Sometimes order is provided by the user input and then it would not be safe to use it directly. But in your case this is not true, and it is absolutely safe to use it as it is. I guess this should be protection against accidental SQL injection.

Comment: In the case of `Arel.sql` it is part of the rails documentation https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Arel.html. Arel is the part of the ActiveRecord gem and the rest of it is not documented at all.

Comment: So is the thinking that you *can* pass user/network input to the `order` method, but never to `Arel.sql`, so the latter will be when it is safe?

Comment: Yep, when it is safe and you need to use some SQL function in `order` method, always use `Arel.sql`. When you are ordering by some user input data, do not use it and let it fail.

Comment: This works but it generates brakeman warnings/errors. "warning_type": "SQL Injection". You can fix it by adding .order(Arel.sql(sanitize_sql_array('count(*)'))). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67374536/how-to-sanitize-arel-sql