# How to sanitize Arel SQL?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sql-injection, arel

I have the following Arel SQL:

```
Arel.sql("(users.last_donated_at IS NOT NULL AND users.last_donated_at < '#{User::ACTIVE_DONOR_WITHIN_DAYS.days.ago}')")
```

I get `SQL Injection` warning when I run brakeman. I tried the following:

```
Arel.sql("(users.last_donated_at IS NOT NULL AND users.last_donated_at < ?)", User::ACTIVE_DONOR_WITHIN_DAYS.days.ago)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)
```

How do I sanitize sql statement with Arel?

Comment: Try: `Arel.sql([ ... ])` with the surrounding array notation. Is there any reason you're dropping down to Arel vs. just using the regular composition methods?

Comment: When i do  `Arel.sql(["(users.last_donated_at IS NOT NULL AND users.last_donated_at < ?)", "#{User::ACTIVE_DONOR_WITHIN_DAYS.days.ago.to_s(:db)}"])`, it is giving me `no implicit conversion of Array into String`

Comment: What's the goal here? Why not do a simple `where` clause which does support placeholders? Using `Arel` directly is usually a mistake.

Comment: In some Rails versions you could just do `User.where.not(last_donated_at: nil).where('last_donated_at < ?', User::ACTIVE_DONOR_WITHIN_DAYS)`, may I ask whether using Arel is mandatory?

Comment: I am using Ransack gem and it works with Arel syntax. I get `NoMethodError (undefined method eq` if I use anything else. Probably there is a way to make it work with activerecord that I am not aware of

Comment: Maybe there's some `eq` Arel method around there. You could share the error you get in such case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am answering my own question. I am using Arel following the Github wiki for Ransack gem. I was doing something very similar to point # 2.2 mentioned on doc: https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/Using-Ransackers.
In order to sanitize the params and avoid brakeman `sql injection` warning, I ended up doing the following:

```
Arel.sql(sanitize_sql_array("(users.last_donated_at IS NOT NULL AND users.last_donated_at < '#{User::ACTIVE_DONOR_WITHIN_DAYS.days.ago}')"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `Arel.sql` is generally not the best way to handle querying. In my opinion you don't need to sanitize this query you need to refactor it.

You can build conditions for a rails where clause (and most other query methods `order`, `select`, etc.) in `Arel` using the convenience method `ModelName.arel_attribute(:attribute_name)` this will allow you to build query conditions beyond the high level support offered by rails' native where `Hash`.

This is identical to

```
table_name = ModelName.arel_table
table_name[:attribute_name]
```

So let's apply this to your query:

Based on your query the IS NOT NULL condition means nothing since you are also using less than so we can change the condition to just use less than e.g.

```
User.arel_attribute(:last_donated_at).lt(User::ACTIVE_DONOR_WITHIN_DAYS.days.ago)
```

This works because NULL is not less than (or greater than, or even equal to) anything so these results will not show up either way.

If you insist on the IS NOT NULL condition we can still produce the desired SQL using Arel Atrributes via:

```
User.arel_attribute(:last_donated_at).not_eq(nil).and(
  User.arel_attribute(:last_donated_at).lt(User::ACTIVE_DONOR_WITHIN_DAYS.days.ago)
)
```

Comment: I am using Ransack gem. I am doing something similar to point #2.2 as mentioned on doc: https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/Using-Ransackers. I get `undefined method 'eq' for #<Arel::Table:0x00007f928e130308>` if I use Arel table

Comment: @farha I am not sure I understand your issue. Custom ransackers should not include the condition as ransack's predication will take care of that. Unless you are looking for a boolean e.g. true/false in which case I could provide a Arel solution for that as well